# Weird ternary nullpointer

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, ternary-operator

This little snippet causes NPE when `data` isn't `foo` nor `bar`.

```
Boolean baz = data == foo ? true : data == bar ? false : null
```

I'm guessing the compiler interprets the `null` as a `null` `Boolean` and tries to autounbox it, but why? Is it because there are `true`/`false` values present?  If so, shouldn't they just be autoboxed instead? The variable is of type `Boolean` after all.

Comment: May i know what is type of  foo, bar and data?

Comment: The type of `data == foo ? true : data == bar ? false : null` is `boolean`.

Comment: show declaration of foo and bar

Comment: same effect when you use braces around the second ternary?

Comment: Use `Boolean.TRUE` instead of `true` (same for false).

Comment: @AndyTurner It seems you're correct, because if I change `true` to `Boolean.TRUE` and `false` to `Boolean.FALSE` there is no NPE. But what determines the type of the ternary expression? First value returned? After all the `null` at the end has to be `Boolean`

Comment: @mak-g https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25 - see Table 15.25-D particularly.

Comment: @AndyTurner That explains all I wanted to know, thanks.

Comment: @AndyTurner it's not of type `boolean`, it's of type `Boolean`; from your link: "A reference conditional expression is a poly expression if it appears in an assignment context or an invocation context ... The type of a poly reference conditional expression is the same as its target type".

Comment: @daniu it isn't reference conditional expression though, it's boolean conditional expression according to the link's defnition: 

" If both the second and the third operand expressions are boolean expressions, the conditional expression is a boolean conditional expression. 
For the purpose of classifying a conditional, the following expressions are boolean expressions:

    An expression of a standalone form (§15.2) that has type boolean or Boolean. (...)
"

Comment: @mak-g But "If both the second and the third operand expressions are boolean expressions" does not hold for `myBoolean ? true : null`: `null` is not a boolean expression. As an example, the context of this may be `boolean res1 = true; String res2 = null; System.out.println(myBoolean ? res1 : res2);`